# How many cases and what mechanism that would make firebase function retry itself?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

There is mentioned in [the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) that firebase function would throw error and retry if it was not return anything

And so I was thinking that, can we intentionally cause the function to retry itself?

Suppose I was writing a function to hook on firebase database. That function will listen to creation of new user and it will do something then send notification. And I want to retry the whole function if the notification sending is failed

Can I force it to retry? How many times will it retry itself? How many condition that firebase will retry the function?